# formula field that calculates days between two date/time fields excluding weekends

Tags: formula, datetime

Can anyone assist or point me in the direction of an example of a formula field that calculates days between two date/time fields excluding weekends?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004526&type=1

Comment: @NicoleY, in the future, make sure you do your research prior to posting. If you do not find the info, make sure you do mention where you searched and any links that point towards related documentation that you may not understand so we can explain.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example of this in [Help & Training](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004526&type=1), shown below:

```
CASE(MOD( StartDate__c - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 

  0 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
  1 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
  2 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  3 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  4 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  5 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
  6 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
  999) 
  + 
  (FLOOR(( EndDate__c - StartDate__c )/7)*5)
```

Where StartDate__c represents a field to use as the earlier of two dates, and EndDate__c represents a field to use as the later of two dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
(5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE(End_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 )
    + MIN( 5, MOD( DATEVALUE(End_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 )  )
) -
(5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE(Start_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 )
      + MIN( 5, MOD( DATEVALUE(Start_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) )
)
```

Comment: Here Start_Date__c is earlier date and End_Date__c is new one which is less than Start_Date__c